# Tidymodels_Decision tree model: nominal variables

Tags: r, dataframe, data-mining, decision-tree, tidymodels

Everyone! :)
I am a graduate student researcher who uses decision tree analysis to study the determinants of people's overburden of housing costs.

---

I am posting this because I have a question about the classification result of categorical variables.
I think the value of categorical variables has been properly dummyized in the recipe-related code (with step_dummy).

```
################################################################################
##################  PART 1: 패키지 설치 및 데이터 불러오기  ######################
################################################################################
#step1: 패키지 설치/불러오기
#install.packages("foreign")
#install.packages("tidyverse")
#install.packages("tidymodels")
#install.packages("caret'")
#install.packages("themis")
#install.packages("skimr")
#install.packages("naniar")
#install.packages("vip")
library(foreign) #spss 불러오기
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels) #모델 만들기
library(caret) #데이터 분할하기
library(themis)#불균형데이터 해결
library(skimr)#데이터탐색적요약(EDA)
library(vip) #변수 중요도 찾기
library(rpart.plot)#의사결정나무 시각화

#step2: 데이터불러오기
setwd('C:/R_work/thesis/th1')
data1 <- read.spss('RL_1.sav', to.data.frame = T)
str(data1) #변수들 factor, num인 것 확인
head(data1)

#step3: 필요없는 변수제거: RIR, age_range
data1 <- data1 %>%
  select(-c(RIR, age_range))
str(data1)
```

[image]

```
#step4: 데이터 탐색(EDA): base accuracy
data1 %>%
  count(RIR_status) %>%
  mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) #과부담(excess, 693) VS. 비부담(normal, 1710): 불균형

#step5: 데이터분할하기(훈련용:학습용 = 7:3)
set.seed(1234)
split_data1 <- initial_split(data1, prop = 0.7, strata = RIR_status)
split_data1 #데이터 분할완료
train_data1 <- training(split_data1)
test_data1 <- testing(split_data1)
nrow(train_data1) #train데이터: 1682 /2403
nrow(test_data1) #test 데이터: 721 /2403

################################################################################
#####################  PART 2: 모델 만들기(훈련용 데이터)  #######################
################################################################################
#의사결정나무 model 만들기_그냥(그냥/over/under/smote/ROSE)
#step6: 모델 세팅하기 
args(decision_tree)
tree_model <- 
  decision_tree() %>% #기본 parameter사용
  set_engine("rpart") %>%
  set_mode("classification") #모델돌린 것 아님/단순 세팅만 한 상태

#step7: recipe 만들기(불균형데이터_그냥(그냥/up/down/SMOTE/ROSE))
tree_recipe <-
  recipe(RIR_status ~., data = train_data1) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes())
summary(tree_recipe)

#step8: workflow 만들기
tree_workflow <- 
  workflow() %>%
  add_model(tree_model) %>%
  add_recipe(tree_recipe)
tree_workflow

#step9: model 훈련 by training data
tree_train_fit <-
  tree_workflow %>%
  fit(data = train_data1) #모델 훈련하기
tree_train_fit %>%
  extract_fit_parsnip() #모델훈련결과 확인하기
```

However, as a result of the decision tree analysis below, **categorical variables are classified like numerical variables as shown in the figure**.

```
################################################################################
################################  PART 5: 시각화  ##############################
################################################################################
#step15: 시각화(rpart.plot/prp), 정확도 낮으면 -> tuning
rpart_fit <- 
  tree_train_fit %>%
  extract_fit_parsnip()

rpart.plot(x=rpart_fit$fit,
           yesno = 2,
           type = 2,
           extra = 1,
           split.font = 1,
           varlen = -10)
```

[image]

---

Would it be helpful for you to answer if I share the code and result value?

I would appreciate it if you could solve my long-standing problem.
(Sorry for some hashtag codes written in Korean...!)

I think the classification criteria should appear categorically, not job_other<0.5, on the top node.

For example, shouldn't it be classified as regular worker, tempr worker, entrepreneur, and other, which are the criteria I set as a job group questionnaire?

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (for `data1` here specifically). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: It looks like you converted your categorical variables to dummy variables, which means they are numbers now. You might try training your decision tree with your variables in their original state if that's not what you want. You can read more [here](https://www.tmwr.org/recipes.html#dummies) and [here](https://www.tmwr.org/categorical.html#is-an-encoding-necessary).